# active admin: are there more detailed documentation or resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I only come across this:
http://activeadmin.info/documentation.html

but I think many of the features one can choose from are not covered here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for API docs these seem to be current and updated (as of 2018-06-28): https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activeadmin

Answer (score 1):

You can find a lot of code samples and more documentation in the following places:

- Google Group - [groups.google.com/group/activeadmin](http://groups.google.com/group/activeadmin)
- Issue Tracker - https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues

Please remember to use the issue tracker only for technical issues, and the Google Group for advice, code samples, etc. You are always welcome to improve the documentation if you can